# 100 % packet loss

Tags: ssh, static-ip, ping

I am a newbie who is using raspberry pi for the first time.

I connected my rpi to an enterprise wifi network and it looks connected. Still, there is 100% packet loss wheter I am trying to ping google.com or 8.8.8.8

I configured  etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and /etc/network/interfaces as well.

In addition to everything stated above, I edited dhcpcd.conf setting an static ip on my eth interface to connect the rpi by using putty and ssh. Beforehand, the connection was refused.

Is the static ip influencing by any means the wifi connection ?

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: What does `ifconfig` tell you?

Comment: wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:a6:24:45
          inet addr:10.160.84.122  Bcast:10.160.95.255  Mask:255.255.224.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8c33:b374:aec2:c60a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16417 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10511 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:18562838 (17.7 MiB)  TX bytes:1067483 (1.0 MiB)

Comment: 10.160.84.122 is not in the same subnet as your router with 192.168.0.1. That is why you cannot reach out for the internet. Is your `static ip_address` the same value? It definitively should start with 192.168.0.xxx.

Comment: nope, static_ip is the same as my pc's, otherwise putty is not working

Comment: Ah, right. That's ethernet. Looks to me as if your company does not privide you a proper IP address.

Comment: Outgoing ping (icmp packets) could be blocked by firewall - can you ping another device inside LAN from RPi? Can you ping google.com from other device within same network like RPi?

Comment: If you modified `/etc/network/interfaces` you have interfered with the networking. It is difficult to see exactly what you have done (post text not images). See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
and [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)